# Passing classes as parameters in a DLL

Tags: delphi

This [Help page](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/When_to_Use_Packages_and_DLLs) about DLLs, suggest that you can pass classes as parameters in a Delphi/CPPB DLL:

> If you need to pass a TStrings object from a DLL **then using** an is or as operator, you need to create a package rather than a DLL.

Which I read it as:
"You can pass a TStrings object from a DLL if you are NOT  using an is or as operator on them"

[Rudy Velthius](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-dlls.html) says "never pass classes" (and I agree with him).

So, is the documentation sloppy or I interpret it bible-style (however I like it)?

Comment: The documentation is not listing every single problem that arises when you pass class instances between non-package modules. There are lots more. Rudy's advice is fine.

Comment: And yes, the documentation is sloppy. It focuses exclusively on the RTTI, but there are other issues which (I think) are not related to RTTI, or at least not that obviously. The way the documentation is written suggests that there are safe ways to do this, but there aren't. It's either a package, or stick to the primitive, non-Delphi-specific types.

Comment: I might come as slightly pedantic, but I think it's worth mentioning there's no problem passing a class instance to a DLL, as long as the DLL doesn't use it beyond passing it back to the host application, for example, through a callback function.